# Release subview and manage memory

Tags: ios, memory-management, view

I've the following code in the main.m class file

```
-(void)switchView:(UIView *)view1 toView:(UIView *)view2{ 
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Animation" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.75];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.window cache:YES];    
[window addSubview:view2];

[UIView commitAnimations];
    [view1 release];
}
```

I call this method from external files in this way:

```
-(IBAction)menuChangeLanguage:(id)sender{
main *delegate = (main *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
viewController *newView = [[viewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"newController" bundle:nil];
[delegate switchView:self.view toView:newView.view];
}
```

In this way I create a new view and switch with the existing one. Even if I've put the `[view1 release]` command in the method I call, I can see that the allocation of memory increases as I switch between the 2 views. What am I doing wrong?

If I use the analyze instrument it says `Potential leak of an object stored into 'newView'`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: i've made a try using `[view1 removeFromSuperview];` instead of `[view1 release];` but nothing has changed

Comment: So you don't ARC, right? You would have to do boht, remove it from its superview, which reduces the retain count by 1 and you would have to release it again, wich gives up the owndership from the view controllers point of view. But when you do that, you must consider that self.view is still referencing to the in near future released object.

Comment: There's not enough information to diagnose the problem here. Without knowing the retain counts going in, the management of `self.view`, the rest of the code that changes `self.view`, etc, any diagnosis will be based on guesswork. You also appear to be using the very confusing class name `viewController` to refer to a `UIView`, and the way that you instantiate it also looks like a `UIViewController`...is that a view or a view controller?

Comment: you are right, i forgot to add `.view` to the variable viewController (UIViewController): i've edited the code

Comment: Does view 2 have a strong reference to view 1? If so you've got a retain cycle. You want that reference to be weak so it can get cleaned up.

Comment: yes Aaron, it's what i would like to do :) any idea on how? and no, in this project i don't use ARC

Comment: for now i've decided to introduce a singleton class to solve this issue (not a real answer tot the problen but just a turnaround). anyway if someone knows a faster way to do it please submit it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to remove the view from its viewcontroller. UIviewController has a strong reference to its view, so even if you remove from its superview, the view is retained by the viewcontroller.

take a look at the Apple UIViewController Class [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/view)